# Unable to create Dynamic Variables

Tags: php, session

When I check my cookies I do see that PHPSESSID is being made. But when I try to use them I get an error message saying that the variable is undefined.

This is how I set my Sessions:

```
$posts = array("auto_year", "auto_brand", "auto_model", "auto_bodywork", "auto_doors", 
"auto_fuel", "auto_gearbox", "auto_type", "auto_uitvoering", "auto_part", "auto_description", "email_address");

//Define POSTS and set into SESSIONS
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   if (isset($_POST[$post])) {
      $_SESSION[$post] = $_POST[$post];
      $$post = $_SESSION[$post];
   }
}
```

I also tried it manually like:

```
$_SESSION['auto_year'] = '2012';
```

But it still doesn't work. I did call session_start() on top of the pages of both but it just keeps giving me that error.

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Comment: All of the variables that are being made with that foreach. So $auto_year, $auto_brand etc etc

Comment: What happens if you do `var_dump($_SESSION)` after the for loop?

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) tells me that all those variables are set it shows all the right values

Comment: I just noticed that when I call them as for example $_SESSION[['auto_year'] it does work but not when I call $auto_brand but that should be set with $$post = $_SESSION[$post] shouldnt it?

Answer (score 1):

using `${}` you can create dynamic variables. In your case just change to:

`${$post} = $_SESSION[$post];`

Comment: I noticed that the variables were being made somewhere where the other page doesnt have access to it. It was in a if($submit) statement and the other one in another submit. They are in the same file so I didnt think about it like that. Sorry for my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely something wrong with the $_POST data coming from your form.  As I don't have form info, I tried this by setting $_POST.

```
session_start();

$_POST['auto_year'] = 1977;

$posts = array("auto_year", "auto_brand", "auto_model", "auto_bodywork", "auto_doors",
    "auto_fuel", "auto_gearbox", "auto_type", "auto_uitvoering", "auto_part", "auto_description", "email_address");

//Define POSTS and set into SESSIONS
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post."<br>";
    if (isset($_POST[$post])) {
echo "Creating variable for $post<br>";
        $_SESSION[$post] = $_POST[$post];
        $$post = $_SESSION[$post];
        echo '$auto_year: '.$auto_year . "<br>";
    }
}
echo "<br><br>".var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Everything works except for this part: $$post = $_SESSION[$post]; It doesnt throw them in a variable for example $auto_year. The posts are set and the sessions too.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create the variables using extract() which enables you to set all variables in one go;

```
extract($_SESSION);
```

Will create a variable for each key in the session, e.g. $auto_year, $auto_brand, etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

**note**
I'm wondering why you want to have all data in separate variables, whereas a single associative array may be just as easy to handle?